# Seriazlizing arrays in Ajax for php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

i try to serialize my checkbox items.

first, i want to tell you what i want.

i have a form like that,

[image]

User select checboxes and when press the button "Sil" it has to remove the artist.

i prepare an ajax script for that,

```
function deleteData2()
{
    var artistIds = new Array();

    $(".p16 input:checked").serialize()(function(){
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });


    $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', { 'artistIds': artistIds },function(response){
        if(response=='ok')
            alert("ok");
    });


}
```

My ajax script has movie id and artist id, it has these datas. The actual problem is that, ajax cannot send this data to php. I make some research about it and then i reached that  i have to serialize my array and add my `$(".p16 input:checked").serialize()(function(){` script serialize but also does not works.

```
public function deleteDataAjax2() {

        extract($_POST);

        if (isset($artistIds))
            $this->sendJSONResponse('ok');

    }
```

above code is my php. and artistIds is always empty so my serialize function does not work.

What might be wrong ? How can i reach my artistIds in php side?

**EDIT**

finally, i come to this

```
  var artistIds = new Array();

    $(".p16 input:checked").each()(function(){
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });


    $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', JSON.stringify({ 'artistIds': artistIds }),function(response){
    if(response=='ok')
        alert("ok");
    });
```

and in php side,

```
public function deleteDataAjax2() {

         extract($_POST);

         $a = json_decode($artistIds);

        if (!empty($a))
            $this->sendJSONResponse('ok');

    }
```

it's still wrong

Comment: can you give data of $_POST variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".p16 input:checked").serialize()(function(){
    artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

this is still giving you an array of artistids, so you can't send it to server, you need to convert it into JSON format first then you can submit it to server like this

```
$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', JSON.stringify({ 'artistIds': artistIds }),function(response){
    if(response=='ok')
        alert("ok");
});
```

and make sure to decode that json data on server before using it using json_decode function

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".p16 input:checked").serialize()(function(){
artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

I think these lines don't work, since I've tried them on Chrome and they give me an error.
I think you may want to use the [`each` function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) of jQuery  for doing something like:

```
$(".p16 input:checked").each(function(){
   artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
 $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', { 'artistIds': artistIds },...
```

After that you'll have the `$artistIds` set as a PHP array.

The [extract method](http://php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php) isn't recomended for using with request variables since it can introduce some security flaws.